# InternetReadFile to Char* in C

Tags: c, wininet

I'm having a bit of a problem with the following code. I've seen tons of examples for using InternetReadFile to save to a file. But I cant find one, or get it to work for a char[]. I want to add the szBuffer up to get holdBuff, and then set content equal to holdBuff.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

HINTERNET hSession;
void urlToChar(char* url, char** content);

int main()
{
    hSession = InternetOpen("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Poison", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    char* content;
    urlToChar("http://google.com/", &content);
    printf("%s",content);
    return 0;
}

void urlToChar(char* url, char** content)
{
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T(""),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = InternetOpenUrl(hSession, url, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (hRequest)
    {
        char holdBuff[] = "";
        char szBuff[1025];
        memset(szBuff, 0x00, sizeof(szBuff));
        DWORD bytesRead;
        while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, szBuff, 1024, &bytesRead) == TRUE && bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // Cat szBuff to holdBuff
            memset(szBuff, 0x00, sizeof(szBuff));
        }
        *content = holdBuff;
        // memset(holdBuff, 0x00, sizeof(holdBuff));  <-- Need this?
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
}
```

Comment: No error, I just haven't found the right code to concatenate szBuff to holdBuff

Comment: Ah, now I see why there's a comment in your loop. I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable declaration

```
char xyz[] = "Hello World!";
```

will tell the compiler to put the contents of the string on the stack. Of course, the stack goes away when your function returns.

So in your case:

```
char holdBuff[] = "";
...
*content = holdBuff;
```

This tells the compiler to create a string of length one (the NULL terminator) as a local variable. Just because you've set the value of `content` to `holdBuff` doesn't mean that what `holdBuff` was pointing exists anymore.

You have to correct two things. Firstly, you must use `strcpy()` or similar function. Second, you must allocate sufficient space for `holdBuff`.

Example:

```
char holdBuff[4096];    // or some other sufficiently large size
...
*content = malloc (strlen(holdBuff) + 1);
strcpy (*content, holdBuff);
```

You'll then need to `free(content)` in `main()` once you're finished with it.

---

Now, for how to actually do the concatenation: Your performance will be much better if you forget about using `szBuff` at all and just write directly to `holdBuff`.

```
char* temp = holdBuff;
while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, temp, 1024, &bytesRead) == TRUE && bytesRead > 0)
{
    temp += bytesRead;
}
*temp = '\0';    // manually append NULL terminator
```

Now `holdBuff` will have the data you want with no need for intermediary concatenation.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out for the past day or so over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
void urlToChar(char* url, char** content)
{
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T(""),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = InternetOpenUrl(hSession, url, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    if (hRequest)
    {
        char holdBuff[] = "";   //do not use fixed size char array and allocate buffer in stack,you can allocate large enough buffer in heap,but recommend you can use string or CString
        char szBuff[1025];
        memset(szBuff, 0x00, sizeof(szBuff));
        DWORD bytesRead;
        while (InternetReadFile(hRequest, szBuff, 1024, &bytesRead) == TRUE && bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // Cat szBuff to holdBuff
            //strcat when using char array
            // operator+ when using stl string
            // [stl string][1]
            memset(szBuff, 0x00, sizeof(szBuff));
        }
        *content = holdBuff;
        // memset(holdBuff, 0x00, sizeof(holdBuff));  <-- Need this?
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
}
```

Comment: Highlight your code and press the "code" formatting button (the 1010 thing).